# nginx - read custom header set on client

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy. I am trying to read a custom header set on the client, so I can update a variable with the value of that header.

I set the header in an XHR request similar to 
xhr.setRequestHeader(‘X-My-Custom-Variable', "1");
xhr.setRequestHeader(‘X-My-Second-Custom-Variable’, 'some-value');

From the docs, I see that I can achieve this on nginx with:

```
if ($http_x_my_custom_variable = ‘1’) {
    set $variable $http_x_my_second_custom_variable;
}
```

However, this doesn’t work when I run it, $variable is not set.

I have also tried using nginx map keyword like so:

```
map $http_x_my_custom_variable $variable {
   default “”;
   “1” $http_x_my_second_custom_variable;
}
```

and still nothing happens.

I have also confirmed that both headers are set to what I expect on the backend Django server.

**Note**: My actual header names looks more like: X-ABM-ZHR-XAVIER. I only state this just incase it might have something to do with the structure of the header name. Although I have also tried different permutations of header names just in case.

Comment: Might the issue be that we’re not entering in the “if statement”? Meaning that $http_x_my_custom_variable is not actually set to “1”?

Comment: I don't think so. I confirmed that the header is set to "1" on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Try not using any dash in the variable name.

From client side pass XMyCustomVariable and on nginx read it with $http_XMyCustomVariable (or lowercase).

I know it is not elegant but as a first step towards debugging, I would confirm that part.

Also, try using one of the known variable names (again for debugging) e.g. send the variable 1 value in user agent header and check on nginx using  $http_user_agent